# Can a method do a return on the calling method? c#

Tags: c#, return

Can a method do a return on the calling method?

```
void Main()
{
   Returner(); //how can i return here... 
   DoNotCallDueToReturn();
}

void Returner()
{
   return //... from here?
}

DoNotCallDueToReturn()
{
   Console.WriteLine("You failed to return");
}
```

Comment: Throw an excepti— oh wait never mind.

Comment: Both of your methods are `void` (so they don't return anything), so I'm not sure I understand the question.  What do you mean by `return` in this case?

Comment: What do you mean by 'do a return' Both methods DO return becuase you 'run off the end of them'

Comment: Just out of curiosity why do you want to do that?

Comment: Do you mean `return;` to short-cut a method with `void` return type?

Comment: Modified it to make it slightly clearer. I had a method that would return if something happened, i refactored this out into it's own method and wondered if you could return from there. It looks like you cant and i'll have to return a bool and check that to decide if to return on main.

Comment: @SteveRowbotham yep, exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second method would have to return a value:

```
int Main()
{
    return Returner();
}

int Returner()
{
    return something;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
void Main()
{
   if (!Returner()) 
   {
      return;
   }
}

bool Returner()
{
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you need to return a status, like true/false in a `bool` and decide in the caller if you want to return.

```
void Main()
{
   if(!Validate())
   {
       return;
   }
}

// returns false if vaildation fails
bool Validate()
{
   return false; // or true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Can a method do a return on the calling method?

No.

> how can i return here...

```
void Main()
{
   Returner(); 
   return;
   DoNotCallDueToReturn(); 
}
```